# Assembly Initialization Error: File not found. Something weird about the used reference

Tags: c#

I moved one project from solution A to solution B using TFS move (with uncommitted changes). I got compile time errors since the references were not found. There were 2 references used. I removed and added them again and compile time errors were fixed. I ran a test case and I get file not found exception.

As per the reference properties, the Path of used reference is `C:_src\HIP\Out\Debug\CIP\Bin\amd64\DataPipe\MaterializedEntityManagerTest\Caradigm.Platform.Pipeline.MaterializedEntityManager.dll`

As per the error below, I think it is looking for this, `file:///C:/_src/HIP/Out/Debug/CIP/Test/amd64/DataPipe/MaterializedEntityManager`

Note that it is looking for it in the folder structure -  **..\CIP\Test** instead of **..\CIP\Bin**. This file does not exist in the Test folder. ANyways I decided to copy to the test folder and give it a shot, the folder being...  `C:_src\HIP\Out\Debug\CIP\test\amd64\DataPipe\MaterializedEntityManagerTest\Caradigm.Platform.Pipeline.MaterializedEntityManager.dll.`
 Unexpectedly, I still get the same error.

I'm now going crazy with this error. What am i missing???

```
Test Name:  CdcEnableWithNoTableTest
Test FullName:  Caradigm.Platform.Pipeline.MaterializedEntityManager.Test.DefiningQueryParserTests.CdcEnableWithNoTableTest
Test Source:    c:\_src\HIP\prod\test\DataPipeline\MaterializationTest\EntityViewManagerTest\DefiningQueryParserTests.cs : line 15
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00

Result Message: 
Assembly Initialization method Caradigm.Platform.Pipeline.MaterializedEntityManager.Test.UnitTestInitializer.AssemblyInitialize threw exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Caradigm.Platform.Pipeline.MaterializedEntityManager, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a03c60abe3a7c396' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Caradigm.Platform.Pipeline.MaterializedEntityManager, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a03c60abe3a7c396
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/_src/HIP/Out/Debug/CIP/Test/amd64/DataPipe/MaterializedEntityManager
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : Caradigm.Platform.Pipeline.MaterializedEntityManager.Test, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a03c60abe3a7c396.
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 12.0\COMMON7\IDE\COMMONEXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\TESTWINDOW\vstest.executionengine.x86.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Caradigm.Platform.Pipeline.MaterializedEntityManager, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a03c60abe3a7c396
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/_src/HIP/Out/Debug/CIP/Test/amd64/DataPipe/MaterializedEntityManager/Caradigm.Platform.Pipeline.MaterializedEntityManager.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/_src/HIP/Out/Debug/CIP/Test/amd64/DataPipe/MaterializedEntityManager/Caradigm.Platform.Pipeline.MaterializedEntityManager/Caradigm.Platform.Pipeline.MaterializedEntityManager.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/_src/HIP/Out/Debug/CIP/Test/amd64/DataPipe/MaterializedEntityManager/Caradigm.Platform.Pipeline.MaterializedEntityManager.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/_src/HIP/Out/Debug/CIP/Test/amd64/DataPipe/MaterializedEntityManager/Caradigm.Platform.Pipeline.MaterializedEntityManager/Caradigm.Platform.Pipeline.MaterializedEntityManager.EXE.
. Aborting test execution.
Result StackTrace:  at Caradigm.Platform.Pipeline.MaterializedEntityManager.Test.UnitTestInitializer.AssemblyInitialize(TestContext context)
```

Comment: Have you tried to install the assembly in GAC? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: We do not use the GAC in our app yet. I cant change it to GAC, not an option.